# Export Postgres Docker image from M1 mac to Window

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to move a docker container with postgreSQL 9.2.23 from a m1 mac to another windows pc for dev.

i commited the container to image and save the image to tar in my M1 mac.
And i load that image.tar in my windows PC.

The image is successfully loaded but when i run that, it say "runtime: failed to create new OS thread".

```
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)

fatal error: newosproc


runtime stack:

runtime.throw(0xf0b54, 0x9)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x80

runtime.newosproc(0x4420022000, 0x4420031fc0)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:160 +0x1e0

runtime.newm(0xfddb8, 0x0)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1572 +0x144

runtime.main.func1()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:126 +0x2c

runtime.systemstack(0x162d00)

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:237 +0x90

runtime.mstart()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1079


goroutine 1 [running]:

runtime.systemstack_switch()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:186 +0x8 fp=0x442001c760 sp=0x442001c750

runtime.main()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:127 +0x5c fp=0x442001c7b0 sp=0x442001c760

runtime.goexit()

/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_arm64.s:983 +0x4 fp=0x442001c7b0 sp=0x442001c7b0
```

Comment: Can you just `docker run` a new container on the target system?  The path you're describing isn't a best practice and has a couple of major problems (the committed image isn't reproducible, it's the wrong CPU architecture, and it will not include the database data).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.